# Push ViewController full screen from bottom inside ModalView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Inside my app I have a `MainVC`. From there I `present` another `ViewControllerB` and I would like to `push` inside there so this is how I achieve this:

```
let ViewControllerB = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: communityVC)
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is working exactly how I want it to work. However in
`ViewControllerB` I also would like to `push` a certain `ViewControllerC` *full screen*  from *bottom* and NOT just inside the `modalView`. I am calling this:

```
let firstLaunchVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstLaunchVC")
let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
transition.type = CATransitionType.push
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstLaunchVC, animated: true)
```

This is `pushing` from the `bottom` but NOT `fullscreen`. I also get this message in the terminal:

> Setting modalPresentationStyle once <UINavigationController: 0x1060f2a00> has been presented will have no effect until it is dismissed and presented again.

How can I push fullscreen from a `presented` `ViewController`?

I hope I made my problem clear. Let me know if you need more information on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling this:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstLaunchVC)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

This is working exactly how I want it to work, even though I am not quite sure if I am messing up my `ViewController-Hirarchy`... anyway it is working :D thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

#### Coordinator for transition - UINavigationControllerDelegate

Create a simple class that will conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, I won't get into details but the main method which is the answer for your question is `navigationController(_:animationControllerFor:from:to:)`

Inside body of this method you can retrieve the operation which is being performed (push, pop...), additionally you can make a decision for animator based upon the view controllers (from, to).

In case you want **default** animator just return **nil**.

---

#### Example

```swift
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
   switch operation {
   case .push: // For push method
       return YourCustomAnimator() //Conforming to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`
   case .pop:
       return nil // For pop we want default animation
   // I skipped the default case
   }
    
   // CASE 2 

   // Or for example you want to make custom animation only for specific view controller
   if toVC is SpecialViewController {
      return YourCustomAnimator()
   }

   return nil // for the rest use default animation
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I changed the question. I didnt make the problem clear in the first place. I hope it is now